# VBA If statement in For Loop and Undefined Ranges

Tags: vba

I am new to coding and am starting off on VBA. This isn't a homework assignment but a little project my dad challenged to me figure out. His instructions were:

Given an unspecified number of values in column A, determine if each value is less than OR is greater than or equal to 5. If the number is less than 5, print "Yes" in the cell next to it in column B. If the number is greater than or equal to 5, print "No". If the value in column A is not a numerical value or is blank, print "Non numeric entry".

Here is my problem: I can't seem to get the For loop to work with the nested If Statement. Do I need a counter? And what would I set as the range for the new entries in column B?

Here is my current code:

```
Sub practice()

    Range (Cells(1,1), Cells(Rows.Count, 1). End(xlUp)).Select

    For Each cell In Selection.Cells
        If cell.value < 5 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range().Value = "Yes"

        Else cell.value >= 5 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range().Value = "no"

        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range().Value` should be `cell.Offset(0, 1).Value` and `Else` should be `ElseIf`.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid using `Select` and `Seletion`, and use fully qualified Range instead. You can do this by fully qualify your `Range` with `Worsheets("Sheet3")`.

You can use `C.Offset(, 1).Value` to modify the value in the cell to the right (Column B).

Try the code below:

```
Sub practice()

    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim C As Range

    Set Rng = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A" & Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(Worksheets("Sheet3").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)

    For Each C In Rng
        If Not IsNumeric(C.Value) Or IsEmpty(C.Value) Then
            C.Offset(, 1).Value = "Non numeric entry"
        Else
            If C.Value < 5 Then
                C.Offset(, 1).Value = "Yes"
            Else
                If C.Value >= 5 Then
                    C.Offset(, 1).Value = "No"
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next C

End Sub
```